# Probabilities having rational mass at finitly many rational points are dense in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, random-variables, weak-convergence

we know that probabilities with finite support are dense in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. See Theorem 6.3 from *Probability Measures on Metric Spaces* by K.R.Parthasarathy.

I just want to know if this Theorem extended for rationals, that is probabilities having rational mass at finitly many rational points are dense in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$

Then how to show that?

Comment: You can consider $\mu = \sum v_\alpha \varepsilon_{x_\alpha},$ where $\alpha$ runs over a finite index set. Consider now rationals $r_\alpha$ such that $\sum |v_\alpha - r_\alpha|  < \varepsilon.$ Construct $\mu_\varepsilon$ akin to $\mu$ replacing $v$ with $r.$ This should do.

Comment: @WilliamM.  I would appreciate if you provide a detailed answer below.

Comment: What is the metric?

Comment: @WilliamM. I guess any metric should work since you are in finite dimensional scenario.